# Get value from input fields through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I am working on a form where there user can add multiple inputs like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--

   var counter = 0;
   var limit = 4;
   window.onload = moreFields;
   function moreFields() {
    if (counter == limit) {
              alert('You have reached the limit of adding ' + counter + ' inputs');
         }
         else

    var newFields = document.getElementById('sa-groep').cloneNode(true);
        newFields.id = '';
        newFields.style.display = 'block';

    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        var hetId = newField[i].id
        if (hetId)
            newField[i].id = hetId + counter;
    }

    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);

    counter++;
    }
```

This works fine, all input get their unique id, but then i figured out that to catch all the input values it is better through `getElementsByClassName`
so then i made this to catch the values:

```
function getClassValue() {

    var secAut = [];
    var readyItems = document.getElementsByClassName('SA');
        for(var i = 0; i < readyItems.length; i++){
        secAut.push(readyItems[i].value);
        document.write(3011+i+  " contains: " + secAut[i] + "<br />");
        }
        }
```

the html code is:

```
<body>

<div id="sa-groep" style="display: none">
    <input class="SA" id="sa_" value=" " /> 

    <select class="RC" id="rc_"> 
        <option>Rating</option>
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good">Good</option>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <input type="button" value="Remove review"
        onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)" /><br /><br />

</div>

    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!" />

    <input type="button" onclick="getClassValue()" value="Send form" />

</body>
```

But the only thing it show is : 3011 contains: So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you even need ids?

Comment: Well no, as long as i can get the values from the input fields. I can delete that bit in the duplicate field function.

Answer (score 0):

At first look I suggest you to change document.write (which replace all the text of your document) and instead use console.log("something..") or the property innerHTML in a specific div.

document.write, as I said before, replace all the the page with the string passed.

Comment: Okay, so there is "nothing" wrong with catching the values but to display them? I've got now three suggestions: Append, console.log or innerHTML. I will look into those

Comment: With 'console.log' i did get results. With 'alert' it even worked like i would. Then i saw also the problem: the 'getElementByClassName' takes also the first occurrence wich is hidden and there for empty. I cant read an array from index 1 so there for i must find a way to cloneNode with an empty input field.

Comment: @Sturmgas first of all, it's document.getElementsByClassName (elements not element). This return an array with all the HTML elements with that class, so may you need to cicle the array. See also querySelector, it's pretty cool ;)

Comment: that was a typo in my comment in the function its typed allright. I can now the delete the first element from the hidden `.class` by means of `shift()` But i will have a look in to querySelector

Answer (score 0):

In this function the loop needs to start from 1 because the 0th element is the hidden (cloned) one.

```
function getClassValue() {

  var secAut = [];
  var readyItems = document.getElementsByClassName('SA');

  for (var i = 1; i < readyItems.length; i++) {
    secAut.push(readyItems[i].value);
    document.write(3011+i+  " contains: " + secAut[i - 1] + "<br />");
  }
}
```

There are a couple of other problems, missing curly brace after the else in moreFields.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfsgwd2u/5/)

Comment: Yeah, i figured that. but somehow the fiddle with 'var i = 1' doesnt work either, get an "undefined". I delete that 0th element with 'shift()'

Comment: Oops, the last change I made to the fiddle broke it.  The output needs to use secAut[i - 1].

Comment: mmm than it should work without `shift()`. I will try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem beside the curly bracket (thanks @James) was the cloning of an hidden fields wich gave an empty result at the first spot in the arrays. To delete the first element of an array i had to delete that with `shift()` It works, probably it can be better but this is my solution:

```
function getClassValue() {

var secAut = [];    // array met de namen van de secundaire auteurs
var readyItems = document.getElementsByClassName('auteur');
    for(var i = 0; i < readyItems.length; i++){
    secAut.push(readyItems[i].value);
    }
var secAutMinus = secAut.shift(); // 1 element verwijdert uit array ivm dat de eerste input leeg is (display: none)

var relCode = [];   // 2e array met de relatiecodes
var relCodeready = document.getElementsByClassName('relcode');
for(var i = 0; i < relCodeready.length; i++){
    relCode.push(relCodeready[i].value);
    }
var relCodeMinus = relCode.shift(); // 1st element verwijderen

    for(var k= 0; k < secAut.length; k++){
    console.log(3012+k+  ' contains: ' + secAut[k] + ' is ' + relCode[k] + '<br/>'); //  uitlezing arrays minus het eerste lege element
    }
    }
```